# Add an image attribute to a Magento product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Suppose I have a clothes e-commerce and I have a Clothes attribute set with clothing_size. The e-commerce manager wants to be able to attach an image to the product that will display some laundry instructions.

I thought I could accomplish that by creating an attribute typed 'Image Media' and add it to the Clothes attribute set.

I set it as:

```
Code: launtry_instructions_image
Scope: Global
Entry type: Media Image
Apply to: [Simple Product, Configurable Product]
```

I hoped that would give the store manager a file input so he could upload an image, but I was wrong. Nothing changed.

Am I missing something or there's no simple way of accomplishing that?

Thnak you in advance.

#### Edit

As @marius pointed out this input will be placed in the Images tab.

I was able to get the image by

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'laundry_instructions_image');
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should see an other column in the `Images` tab.

Comment: @Marius, why don't you create an answer instead of comment so I can mark it as correct? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new image attribute should appear as a column inside the `Images` tab.